# Error casting SqlDataReader DataItem to DataRowView on RowBound event of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, casting, ado.net

I have a GridView which I assign the DataSource and Bind like this:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("XXX", con))
    {
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // parameter declarations are here

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        gvResults.DataSource = rdr;
        gvResults.DataBind();

    }
}
```

There is then an OnRowBound method which looks like this:

```
protected void gvResults_OnRowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;

    if (row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

    DataRowView rowdata = (DataRowView)row.DataItem;

    // fancy stuff will happen here

}
```

When then line that attempts to cast the row's DataItem to DataRowView is reached an error is thrown which reads:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

I understand that I'm obviously not casting this DataItem to the right kind of class, but my question is **what is the right class to be casting to when the DataSource is a SqlDataReader**?

Or am I on the wrong track completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct type would be `IDataRecord`